# Array of tables with each array index is unique

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table which contains IDs for different products

```
Products = {
      ['A']  = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 },
      ['B']  = { 0x11 },
      ['C']  = { 0x20, 0x22 }
}
```

When I read product ID register, the value is one of above Unique IDs(i-e 0x03) I am trying to read Which product this ID corresponds to. For exapmle how to get Key = 'A' from ID=0x03?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to search the table:

```
function findproduct(id)
        for k,v in pairs(Products) do
                for _,i in pairs(v) do
                        if i==id then return k end
                end
        end
end
print(findproduct(0x03))
```

If the table is long and you need to do this very often, consider building an index:

```
Index = {}
for k,v in pairs(Products) do
        for _,i in pairs(v) do
                Index[i]=k
        end     
end     
print(Index[0x03])
```

Comment: +1 for creating index. Since my table will not expand very often. I could rebuild the table like Keys = IDs and Value = Products. but this will not look very logical for the reader in future. Is there a way to build index table while I declare the Products ={} table? I mean if i can skip the function call to findproduct() ?

Comment: @waqas_sha, you could wrap the second piece of code into a function `MakeIndex`.